# Return multiple Flux in a single object

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have multiple lists as Flux objects that are coming from differnt database queries.
Now I want to create an object where I can put all my Flux objects into and return it to the client.

Example:

```
    public Mono<TestDto> getOverview() {
      Flux<TestResult> a = repo.findA();
      Flux<TestResult> b = repo.findB();
      Flux<TestResult> c = repo.findC();
      Flux<TestResult> d = repo.findD();

      // How can I create a single DTO from the 4 Flux objects?

      return dto;
    }

    public class TestDto {
      private Flux<TestResult> a;
      private Flux<TestResult> b;
      private Flux<TestResult> c;
      private Flux<TestResult> d;
}
```

My DTO obviously doesn't work because it's returning the Flux object but not the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two possible methods here depending on what fits your use case best.

If you want to have a single `TestDto` object that's returned reactively via a `Mono<TestDto>`, then alter your DTO to contain lists rather than publishers, and give it an all argument constructor:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestDto {
  private List<TestResult> a;
  private List<TestResult> b;
  private List<TestResult> c;
  private List<TestResult> d;
}
```

...then you can use `Mono.zip()` along with `collectList()` to return a `Mono<TestDto>` as so:

```
return Mono.zip(arr -> new TestDto((List<TestResult>)arr[0],(List<TestResult>)arr[1],(List<TestResult>)arr[2],(List<TestResult>)arr[3]), a.collectList(), b.collectList(), c.collectList(), d.collectList());
```

The above is probably what you want, and is the most "normal" approach. The following probably isn't what you're after, but it's included for the sake of completeness.

If however you know that each of your `Flux` publishers will always have the same number of elements, and you want to reactively stream a `Flux<TestDto>` to the client (where each individual TestDto contains a TestResult from a, b, c & d) then you could modify your TestDto to just contain a single value of each TestResult:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestDto {
  private TestResult a;
  private TestResult b;
  private TestResult c;
  private TestResult d;
}
```

Then you can return a `Flux<TestDto>` by zipping as follows:

```
return Flux.zip((Object[] arr) ->
  new TestDto((TestResult)arr[0],(TestResult)arr[1],(TestResult)arr[2],(TestResult)arr[3]), a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: The first approach is exactly what I was looking for. Even though a,b,c and d are all of the same type, they contain different aggregates and are independent from each other.
Thanks for your help.